# CefSharp Resources not loading when using LoadHTML

Tags: c#, html, chromium-embedded, cefsharp

I'm using [CefSharp](https://github.com/chillitom/CefSharp) for showing a html file in `CefSharp browser`.

when I use `web_view.Load(@"C:\htmlfile.htm");` it's show my body background.

but when i load `htmlfile.htm` and use `web_view.LoadHtml(File.ReadAllText(@"C:\in.htm"));` body background doesn't show?

I want to ask how do i must set address body background in html local file?

**This is My Html File content:**

```
<html>
<body background="C:\Untitled.png">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
web_view.LoadHtml(File.ReadAllText(@"C:\in.htm"), @"C:\in.htm");
```

The second parameters indicates the URL, if the URL is a local resource then, the page will be able to load local resources.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to implement `IRequestHandler.OnBeforeResourceLoad()`, intercept each request, and read the bytes yourself from disk and suppy them to chromium as a response.

https://github.com/chillitom/CefSharp/blob/master/CefSharp/IRequestHandler.h#L26

Answer (score 0):

Another way you could do this is use a schemeHandler (it's cleaner IMO).

- Register a scheme with CEF -

> CEF.RegisterScheme("ascheme", new HandlerFactory());

- Add a scheme handler that loads the PNG from disk and returns a relevant response
- then change your html to refer to the scheme:

> body background="myscheme://Untitled.png"

I can fill in the blanks if need be... but that should be enough!